# Setting up AsyncTask to call other methods

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an app that runs a basic TicTacToe game, stores leaderboard data and saves it to a file. This functionality is all split up across various java files. The TicTacToe game is stored in its own java file/activity. It takes in the username that is set from another activity.

I have to make the game run using AsyncTask. I've implemented the methods and tried passing them void and then calling the game methods from inside the `onPreExecute` `doInBackground` and `onPostExecute` but I cant get it to work properly. I also get errors when passing `void` as an argument for AsyncTask class.

`How can I call the methods inside the AsyncTask to make the game playable?`

Included is the full source code for the game, it is fully functional.

**PlayGameActivity**

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.StreamCorruptedException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class PlayGameActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button[][] buttons = new Button[3][3];

    private boolean player1Turn = true;

    private int roundCount;

    private int player1Points;
    private int player2Points;

    private TextView textViewPlayer1;
    private TextView textViewPlayer2;


    //MainMenuActivity MMA = new MainMenuActivity();

    public String subFolder = "/userdata";
    public String file = "test.ser";
    Map<String, Integer> userList = new HashMap<>();

    String inputName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_game);

        SharedPreferences result = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
        inputName = result.getString("username", "");


        textViewPlayer1 = findViewById(R.id.text_view_p1);
        textViewPlayer2 = findViewById(R.id.text_view_p2);

        textViewPlayer1.setText(inputName +":");
        textViewPlayer2.setText("Android:");

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                String buttonID = "button_" + i + j;
                int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", getPackageName());
                buttons[i][j] = findViewById(resID);
                buttons[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);
            }
        }

        Button buttonReset = findViewById(R.id.button_reset);
        buttonReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                resetGame();
            }
        });
    }

    public void startAsyncTask(View v) {

    }
//The void arguments are causing issues
    private class ExampleAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<void, void, void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void doInBackground(void... voids) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!((Button) v).getText().toString().equals("")) {
            return;
        }

        if (player1Turn) {
            ((Button) v).setText("X");
        } else {
            ((Button) v).setText("O");
        }

        roundCount++;

        if (checkForWin()) {
            if (player1Turn) {
                player1Wins();
            } else {
                player2Wins();
            }
        } else if (roundCount == 9) {
            draw();
        } else {
            player1Turn = !player1Turn;
        }

    }

    private boolean checkForWin() {
        String[][] field = new String[3][3];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                field[i][j] = buttons[i][j].getText().toString();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (field[i][0].equals(field[i][1])
                    && field[i][0].equals(field[i][2])
                    && !field[i][0].equals("")) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (field[0][i].equals(field[1][i])
                    && field[0][i].equals(field[2][i])
                    && !field[0][i].equals("")) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (field[0][0].equals(field[1][1])
                && field[0][0].equals(field[2][2])
                && !field[0][0].equals("")) {
            return true;
        }

        if (field[0][2].equals(field[1][1])
                && field[0][2].equals(field[2][0])
                && !field[0][2].equals("")) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void writeSettings(View v) {
        File cacheDir = null;
        File appDirectory = null;

        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().
                equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            cacheDir = getApplicationContext().getExternalCacheDir();
            appDirectory = new File(cacheDir + subFolder);

        } else {
            cacheDir = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir();
            String BaseFolder = cacheDir.getAbsolutePath();
            appDirectory = new File(BaseFolder + subFolder);

        }

        if (appDirectory != null && !appDirectory.exists()) {
            appDirectory.mkdirs();
        }

        File fileName = new File(appDirectory, file);

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            out.writeObject(userList);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fos != null)
                    fos.flush();
                fos.close();
                if (out != null)
                    out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }

    }


    public void readSettings(String userName) {
        File cacheDir = null;
        File appDirectory = null;
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().
                equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            cacheDir = getApplicationContext().getExternalCacheDir();
            appDirectory = new File(cacheDir + subFolder);
        } else {
            cacheDir = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir();
            String BaseFolder = cacheDir.getAbsolutePath();
            appDirectory = new File(BaseFolder + subFolder);
        }

        if (appDirectory != null && !appDirectory.exists()) return; // File does not exist

        File fileName = new File(appDirectory, file);

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ObjectInputStream in = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            Map<String, Integer> myHashMap = (Map<String, Integer>) in.readObject();
            userList = myHashMap;

            if (userList.containsKey(userName.toLowerCase())) {
                int count = userList.containsKey(userName) ? userList.get(userName) : 0;
                userList.put(userName, count + 1);
            } else {
                userList.put(userName.toLowerCase(), 1);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            try {
                if (fis != null) {
                    fis.close();
                }
                if (in != null) {
                    in.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    private void player1Wins() {
        player1Points++;
        readSettings(inputName);
        writeSettings(null);
        Toast.makeText(this, inputName + " wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updatePointsText();
        resetBoard();
    }

    private void player2Wins() {
        player2Points++;
        readSettings("android");
        writeSettings(null);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Android wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updatePointsText();
        resetBoard();
    }

    private void draw() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Draw!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        resetBoard();
    }

    private void updatePointsText() {
        textViewPlayer1.setText(inputName + ": " + player1Points);
        textViewPlayer2.setText("Android: " + player2Points);
    }

    private void resetBoard() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                buttons[i][j].setText("");
            }
        }

        roundCount = 0;
        player1Turn = true;
    }

    /*
    * Close the activity
    * */
    private void resetGame() {
//        player1Points = 0;
//        player2Points = 0;
//        updatePointsText();
//        resetBoard();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putInt("roundCount", roundCount);
        outState.putInt("player1Points", player1Points);
        outState.putInt("player2Points", player2Points);
        outState.putBoolean("player1Turn", player1Turn);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        roundCount = savedInstanceState.getInt("roundCount");
        player1Points = savedInstanceState.getInt("player1Points");
        player2Points = savedInstanceState.getInt("player2Points");
        player1Turn = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("player1Turn");
    }

}
```

**activity_play_game.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.tictactoe.PlayGameActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_p1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:text="Player 1: 0"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_p2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_p1"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:text="Player 2: 0"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_reset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="33dp"
            android:text="reset" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_00"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_01"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_02"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_10"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_11"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_12"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_20"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_21"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_22"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask did not accept `void` as an argument, it is `Void` :

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
```

Comment: Thank you, that did fix the errors for passing in Void. Any suggestions on calling the methods?

Comment: @TrickExplanation welcome, accept answer if solved. And for method calling, use AsyncTask only for non-UI task and complex one otherwise calling on UI is fine.

Comment: Im trying to make the gameplay all done in AsyncTask - would you suggest just calling all the game play methods in thee appropriate AsyncTask method then starting AsyncTask on activity load??